# How can I run text selected in the active editor in VS Code's integrated terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to run the select code of python in VS Code. Till now, I have to copy the code and paste it in the terminal below to run. The system is mac OS.
So is there any way to run the code directly after I selected the code? For example, like the shortcuts.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

@yanachen, this is now possible in VS Code. All you need to do is:
1. Ensure python is running in the VS Code terminal window
2. Select the text you wish to execute in python
3. Invoke the command 'workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText' as defined in the following link:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_key-bindings

Comment: I find it seems to be cutting my last quote off in my string.

Answer (score 99):

There is no default keybindings for command "Run Selected Text in Active Terminal", but you can create one.

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to open **File → Preferences → Keyboard Shortcuts**.
- Search for `workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText` in keybindings.
- Press the icon on the left to open a windnow with this message "Press desired key combination..." and make your choice. (I've pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> - as this combination was not used yet.)
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to store your keybinding.

Tested on VSCode 1.30.2 on Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: For dummies like me: Pressing `F1` and starting to type `Run selected text in terminal` should bring up the command rather quickly. With the next `F1` press, it should be at the top of the command list

Answer (score 16):

Now it's supported by default shortcut "shift" + "enter".

1. select the proper code snippet
2. press "shift" + "enter"

Comment: This removes my code too, using Windows 10 and version 1.43.2

Comment: Probably you need to install the intellsense extension on VSCode for Python debug.

Comment: It actually works on my Windows 10, version 21H2.

Comment: works on debian

Comment: @KY Works on Windows with Microsoft Python extension (not "Python Debugger".

Answer (score 5):

Here is the setting for running selection in "interactive window."

In my VS Code (version 1.56.2), I do the following things: go to Settings, search for `interactive window`, in the resulting left panel choose `Jupyter`, and finally check the box next to `Jupyter: Send selection to interactive window`. That's it. One more step for some users (including me) is to modify the keybinding for running selection to your preference. For example, got to `keyboard shortcuts`, type `run selection`, you should see a list of keybindings and you may need to redefine them if conflicts exist.

[image]

Comment: Which extensions do you have installed?

Comment: @Olsgaard I am not sure if this is provided by vs code by default. You may try to install Jupyter Extension for Visual Studio Code as well.

Comment: this worked for me after I changed the key binding for jupyter.execSelectionInteractive to something other than shift-enter.

Answer (score 1):

Some language specific extensions have already an existing keybinding.
On Windows, for the **PowerShell** extension it is currently **F8** to run the selected text.

Answer (score 0):

Install the vscode extension `Node.js Exec`. then select the block of code you want to run and press f8. worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).