# VSCode: How to run active line without highlighting it?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In JupyterLab you can [run code in many different ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56460834/how-to-execute-a-single-line-or-selected-code-in-a-jupyter-notebook-or-jupyterla/56460871#56460871). And I often use the option to run the active line (where the mouse pointer is) using `Run > Run Selected text or current line in console` with a keyboard shortcut. After doing this, the pointer jumps to the next line, and you can keep going.

***Can the same thing be done using VSCode?***

---

And just to be clear, the following is *not* what I'm looking for:

1. `Ctrl+Enter` will run the whole cell.
2. `Shift+Enter` when highlighting a line or or other parts of the code will run that part.
3. `Shift+Enter` with *no highlighted code* runs the whole cell and inserts a new cell below the active cell.

So, how can I run *only* the active line without highlighting it?

A similar question has been asked here: [How to run the select code in VScode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38952053/how-to-run-the-select-code-in-vscode), but that sends code to the **Terminal** and does not provide the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Lets say your py script contains 3 statements: print(something) print(somethingelse) print(4*5). You want to run the 3rd line without highlighting it, right? Lets say the cursor is at the end of the 3rd line and you want to execute only this line. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @SaurabhJain Yes, you are!

Comment: I just pressed SHIFT + Enter at the end of statement and it is executing the 3rd line. Please try

Comment: @SaurabhJain I'm not seeing the same behaviour. `Shift+Enter` runs the entire cell and skips to the next cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to  `file > preferences > keyboard shortcuts`, search for `Run Selection / Line in interactive window` and assign your desired keyboard shortcut. And make sure that there are not conflicts. I found out that several tasks had `Shift + Enter` assigned to it, and that's what had me confused in the first place.