# How to run a shell script with the current line or block of code as argument in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Is there a way to achieve something similar to "Python: Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal " but where the current line of code, or block of code, is passed as an argument to a configurable shell script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I run text selected in the active editor in VS Code's integrated terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38952053/how-can-i-run-text-selected-in-the-active-editor-in-vs-codes-integrated-termina)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) to pass the selected text to the task command

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "echo selected text",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "echo",
      "args": [ "${input:selectedText}" ],
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "selectedText",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.transform",
      "args": {
        "text": "${selectedText}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If needed you can add some arguments to the [`${selectedText}`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable&ssr=false#variable-selectedtext) variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use the variable `${selectedText}` in a keybinding that sends a command to the terminal:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+t",         // whatever you want for a keybinding
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": {
    "text": "echo '${selectedText}'\u000D"
  }
}
```

`\u000D` is a `return` so the command runs immediately.

Or try this keybinding to select the current line first and send that to the terminal:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+t",
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      "cursorHome",
      "cursorEndSelect",
      {
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
        "args": {
          "text": "echo '${selectedText}'\u000D"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Or in a task:

```json
"tasks": [
  {
    "label": "echoMe",
    "type": "shell",

    "command": "echo ${selectedText}",
    "args": [
      
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Nice! And what about getting the content of the current line, or defining the logic to obtain the current block (like in vim), instead of having to make a selection by hand?

Comment: Maybe I figured it out. For single line selection I can probably use runCommands and add editor.action.smartSelect.expand (or similar actions) at the beginning. I will test it as soon as I'm back to my pc.

Comment: I added to the answer for the case of automatically selecting the current line, without first having to manually select it.